# If $f, g \in R [x]$ are monic polynomials, then $fg$ is monic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Prove that if $f, g \in R [x]$ are monic polynomials, then $fg$ is monic.

Prove that the return is false in general.

I am not exactly sure how to prove this, I know that this is done by displaying a pair of nonmonic polynomials such that the product itself is mononic, but I don't know how to turn that into a proof.

Comment: $\frac x2\times(2x)=x^2$

Comment: take two polynomials where you just assume that they are monic (that is you verbatim copy your definition of a monic polynomial) then you multiply them together using ring axioms. Then you contemplate whether the result also satisfies the definition of being monic.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos or if $\frac12$ is not in your ring, maybe try $(-x)\cdot(-x)=x^2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: This won't work in characteristic $2$. In fact for $R$ of characteristic $2$, then the converse might be true (e.g. if $R=\mathbf F_2$ or $R=\mathbf F_2[t]$).

Comment: "false in general" does not mean "always false" because indeed the converse is true when $R$ is the field with 2 elements, or for that matter when $R = 0$. I believe the problem is just looking for a single counterexample in any ring.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: I agree, my main point was that the example given by Hagen von Eitzen does not always work. The rest was just to point out that in cases when it doesn't, it could be that nothing at all could work. $R=0$ is a pretty boring countexample, since there are no monic polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

The converse is not true. For example, take $R={\mathbb Z}/6{\mathbb Z}$. Then $$(2x^2+x+1)(3x+2)=x^2+5x+2.$$

Comment: The zero divisor leading coefficients is a more compelling counterexample than units not equal to one. +1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the leading terms of $f$ and $g$ are $x^m$ and $x^n$ respectively. Then, the leading term of $fg$ is $x^{m+n}$, and so $fg$ is monic.

To show that the converse is false, note that for any unit $u \in R^{\times}$ and any monic polynomial $f$, $f=u(u^{-1}f)$ is a factorization of $f$ as a product of two non-monic polynomials. In particular, if $R$ does not have characteristic $2$, then $f=(-1)(-f)$ would work.

In fact, if $R$ is an integral domain, then a polynomial over $R$ is a divisor of a monic polynomial if and only if its leading coefficient is a unit. This statement is not necessarily true if $R$ is not an integral domain, as Pythagoras' answer shows.